# (javascript) invoke es6 getter using "call"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm trying to create a (class) instance that copies the behavior of another class, but using itself as the state context (this). Normal functions work fine (like the `setValue` function in the example below), but getters do not work. Here is a simple example:

```
const should = require('chai').should();

class One {
    setValue(val) {
        this._val = val;
    }

    get val() {
        return this._val;
    }
}

class Two {
    constructor(one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    setValue(val) {
        this.one.setValue.call(this, val);
    }

    get val() {
        this.one.val.call(this);
    }
}

let one = new One();
let two = new Two(one);
one.setValue(1);
two.setValue(2);
one.val.should.equal(1);
two.val.should.equal(2);
```

The above code explodes on the last line with the error:

```
TypeError: this.one.val.call is not a function
    at Two.get val [as val] (C:\all\code\node-tests\invoke_getter.js:23:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\all\code\node-tests\invoke_getter.js:32:5)
```

How can I make something like this work?

Comment: `get val()` is not a function. It's a getter. You use it like a property. If you need to use it as a function, remove `get` and change it to `getVal`

Comment: `this.one.val.call()` would essentially act as if you had `this.one.val()` yet `this.one.val` just resolves to a value, not to a function handle. Hence why it fails. I'm not totally clear what the end goal is, though - why use `call` and not just `this.one.val`?

Comment: Do you know [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Proxy)? Could it help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that property getters for class ends in its [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

So to access the method, you may want to get it from its prototype:

```
const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(this.one), 'val')
```

Then you can call the getter on your `two` instance:

```js
class One {
  setValue(val) {
    this._val = val
  }

  get val() {
    return this._val
  }
}

class Two {
  constructor(one) {
    this.one = one
  }

  setValue(val) {
    this.one.setValue.call(this, val)
  }

  get val () {
    const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(this.one), 'val')
    return desc.get.call(this)
  }
}

const one = new One()
const two = new Two(one)
one.setValue(1)
console.log(two.val) // undefined (since _val does not exist on two yet)
two.setValue(2)
console.log(two.val) // 2
two._val = 3
console.log(two.val) // 3
```